# NoMethodErrod in RailsAdmin::Main#delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, nomethoderror

I have some problem. I have 2 tables in DB (items, genres, genres_items). When I try delete item from Rails_Admin panel I get error

`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method "items_genres" for #<Item:0x007f0d9571cb50>):
     8:   - else
     9:     = wording
    10:   %ul
    11:     - @abstract_model.each_associated_children(object) do |association, child|
    12:       %li
    13:         - child_config = RailsAdmin.config(child)
    14:         = @abstract_model.model.human_attribute_name association.name`

And when I try delete Genre i get

`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method "genres_items" for #<Item:0x007f0d9571cb50>):
     8:   - else
     9:     = wording
    10:   %ul
    11:     - @abstract_model.each_associated_children(object) do |association, child|
    12:       %li
    13:         - child_config = RailsAdmin.config(child)
    14:         = @abstract_model.model.human_attribute_name association.name`

At first I think that this is a DB error (my DB is on Amazon serv and app in Heroku), but when i setting up app for local DB, I get same problem

Comment: Just guessing, but it looks like you've set up your association to be called "genres_items" or something and then you go and call "items_genres" somewhere.  The vagueness is a reflection of the missing information from you.  You should add to your question A) your associations for each class B) The lines that are being pointed to in the stack trace - look for the first lines that are in your project.  You haven't included the line that the error is actually ocurring on here.

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677214/rails-admin-nomethoderror-in-railsadminmaindelete